# Trying to plot Graph in R with 3 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get a line graph with the following csv file. (just took 10 lines from the file)
Seems i cannot plot the graph to include the DateTime as Y axis and the other 3 (AMK,SK,JR) on the X axis. Anyone can help on this? not sure what the code for this.

```
          DateTime AMK SK JR
1   1/27/2017 6:49  17  3 11    
2   1/27/2017 6:50  17  2 13    
3   1/27/2017 6:51  15  1 14    
4   1/27/2017 6:52  17  1 13    
5   1/27/2017 6:53  17  2 13    
6   1/27/2017 6:54  17  1 10    
7   1/27/2017 6:55  17  1 13    
8   1/27/2017 6:56  16  4 14    
9   1/27/2017 6:57  16  3 10    
10  1/27/2017 6:58  19  3 11
```

Comment: You should propose a code first

Comment: Please can you just give more details about your plot why do you want the Three variable on the X-axis ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a reproducible example of your question, with a possible solution. Since you did not specify exactly what kind of plot you are looking for, I guessed you would like a line plot with 3 different colored lines.

```
DateTime = as.POSIXct('1/27/2017 6:49', format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') + 1:10*60
AMK = c(17,17,15,17,17,17,17,16,16,19)
SK = c(3,2,1,1,2,1,1,4,3,3)
JR = c(11,13,14,13,13,10,13,14,10,11)

df = data.frame(DateTime, AMK, SK, JR)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfplot <- df %>% gather(key, value, -DateTime)

ggplot(dfplot, mapping = aes(x = DateTime, y = value, color = key) ) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: appreciate the answer. that's the graph i am trying to plot.